# Maximum string length for eval

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I have a string of length 65000 that needs to be `eval`ed to convert it into a JSON object.
I get an unexpected token error. I want to know is there any maximum string length above that which `eval` won't work?

Comment: `eval`ing is never a good idea. Let alone `eval`ing a 65k piece of code.

Comment: Use JSON.parse. I've received much greater JSON strings. Where is this string from ? Is it a server response ?

Comment: Did you do `eval( '(' + string + ')' )` or just `eval( string )`. The latter won't work because the `{` is treated as a block opener instead of object initializer

Comment: I tried JSON.parse too- Dint work for such long string

Comment: I tried eval( '(' + string + ')' ) !

Comment: By the way, the string length `eval` can parse does not seem to be limited on software side. Using Firefox 13.1, I was able to parse two million chars.

Comment: What makes you think that you don't just have an error in your JSON?

Comment: Actually ya.. it an invalid json. with a semi-colon at last. But for smaller length strings eval works out perfectly(even with semi colon at last). But for long strings eval throws error as unexpected token ;.

Answer (score 6):

You could always try running it through a JSON parser.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```